# How to prove that $\sin x$ is a lipschitz continuous function on the real line?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

How to prove that the function $\sin x$ is a lipschitz continuous function  on the real line using the definition of lipschitz continuity. I know $|\frac{df}{dx}|\leq 1.$ But I wanted to prove without using this condition.

Answer (score 6):

Use this identity (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities)):
$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos((x+y)/2)\sin((x-y)/2).$$
Hence
$$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq 2|\sin((x-y)/2)|\leq |x-y|.$$
where we used the inequalities $|\cos t|\leq 1$ and $|\sin t|\leq |t|$.